# why does a C++ need a forward declaration either through a header or a statement and Java doesn't need?

Tags: java, c++

Java doesn't complain if you don't forward declare your functions, whereas C++ complains. I know C++ involves preprocessing but I want to understand more..

Comment: External resource: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

Comment: Interestingly, C++ doesn't always require this. Notice that when using a member function (within another member function), you don't have to forward declare it. As far as I know, there isn't a technical restriction that prevents this from being possible (with free-standing functions). But it does tend to make parsing a bit simpler.

Comment: While you asked about Java, Eric Lippert had some comments on C++ vs. C#: [How Many Passes?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/04/how-many-passes.aspx). I suspect much the same reasoning applies to Java, although Java does impose restrictions such as one top level class per file that C# does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Object files**

Java compilers rely on extra information that is compiled into the bytecode (.class) files they produce and which your code uses, while C++ compilers do not store this kind of information in the compiled object code (.obj) files they produces.

Being an older language, C++ relies on the "C model" of program compilation and linkage. This means that object files contain mostly code and data, with only enough metadata needed for object files to be linked together (either statically or dynamically at runtime). Consequently, the compiler relies on header files included while parsing your source code to know about the external class types, functions, and variables your code refers to.

This also means that clients of your C++ code need both the object files (.obj, .lib, or .dll) and header files for your code in order to use it themselves.

Java, being a more modern language, stores a lot of symbolic metadata into the object (.class) files it produces, which allows the compiler to extract the external class types, methods, and variables your code refers to during later compiles.

This also means that clients of your Java code only need the object files (.class or .jar) for your code in order to use it.

**Forward declarations**

Java compilers make multiple passes on the source code, which means that you only need to declare/defined a variable or method in one place within your code; forward declarations are not necessary because the compiler works harder to determine type information.

C++, in contrast, is defined so <del>that it can be implemented as a single-pass compiler, which means</del> that the compiler needs to know all of the relevant type information about a class, variable, or method at the point it is used in your source code. This means that you have to provide that type *declaration* information before the actual object *definition* in your code. This is why header files are used.

Comment: C++ can not be implemented as single-pass compiler.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I am looking for..Now I have to go look for what is single-pass compiler vs multiple-pass compiler.

Comment: @David : doc says C++ cannot be implemented as single-pass?

Comment: @svasa it can not. Read this article http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-compilation-speed/228701711

Comment: Well, true, C++ is too complex to be completely parsed in a single pass. Early versions of C++ (circa cfront) could be, but after adding in full-blown templates, it simply got to complex. But the main point is that the compiler has to be able to deduce the type info at the point of an object's use by all of the source it has seen *up to that point*.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses `.class` file format. Compiler gathers information about class and puts it into `.class` file. In a result linking can be done without involving source files. Note that in Java you have one public class per file requirement, so that for each source `.java` file one `.class` is generated.

In C++ code is usually compiled to `object` files, which have no idea about high level concepts such as classes or structures. Therefore information has to be provided in header files, so that compiler can perform checks (or even to know how to generate some code), before going to link phase.

I was looking for rationale behind forward declarations, but ANSI C by K&R (it's probably a "feature" inherited from C), just states that every variable must be declared before use and that ANSI C made forward declarations of functions consistent with definitions (they were not required to be compatible earlier).

Comment: But the error described is a compile-time error, not a link-time error. While your reasoning could be valid for explaining why forward declarations are required when using multiple object files, it doesn't explain why forward declarations are still required when only one translation unit is used.

Comment: @Cornstalks if C++ compilers were not single-pass when it comes to checking for declarations, forward declarations wouldn't be required. I don't know the rational for this (probably some historical one, like compiler performance). But still, if Java does not need header to compile code that's using another translation unit, then it does not need one (or forward declarations) within the same translation unit.

Comment: @Cornstalks BTW it's not a question about error, but requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Because c++ doesn't have the concept of export modules definitions. If you want to expose a function or a class so other .cpp (modules) can access to it you have to forward declare them in a .h file. Why not write the entire functions (definition) and classes inside the .h instead of forward declare them and write down in a .cpp file?  Because when you do #include it pretty much includes the content of the entire .h file in the .cpp so if you include it in all the .cpp files you have, it will be compiled repetitively in each .cpp. which could be extremely inefficient. So you only want forward declaration in a .h and all the definitions in a .cpp.