# Why does c++ stick to this kind of symbol system?

Tags: c++

The system I mean is the one where anything you want to reference has to be prototyped or defined either above your current line or in a referenced header, not sure if this has a name.

I'm cool with headers but sometimes the necessity of forward prototypes forces me into writing really disjointed and hard to manage snippets.

I get why it was a thing once upon a time but is there any reason modern c++ can't bring us the convenience of allowing definitions in any order, anywhere like the plethora of newer managed languages?

Comment: Because if you want a managed language, use a managed language. C++ is not a managed language.

Comment: that just sounds bitter, what does being managed have to do with a more convenient symbol system?

Comment: Because you associate them with managed languages. C++ is not a managed language. This not being bitter. This is stating a fact.

Comment: I asked the same question sometime ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176077/why-does-a-c-need-a-forward-declaration-either-through-a-header-or-a-statement), basically its the way C++ compiler works.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik just because it exists on managed languages doesn't mean its exclusive to them

Comment: "managed" has nothing to do with this

Comment: I'd suggest that if your code is "hard to manage" due to having prototypes then you have greater problems with your code design. You can look at it as an offshoot of the idea of separation of interface and implementation. The prototype specifies an interface that you want to show the world.

Answer (score 1):

This is inherited from `C`. `C` is designed to be minimal, focusing on simple implementation, in this case the compiler implementation, rather than functionality-completeness or providing a right way to do things.

This "mechanism not policy" philosophy has proven to be successful in early days when there are not much experience in general software industry. So `C` and `Unix` make few choices, and try to remain as simple and general as possible. This rules out a lot of premature choices, and is one of the reasons why `C` (and `Unix`) remains relevant even today 40 years after the birth.

This has been arguably changed. Software industry now amassed a lot of experiences in what a good language should look like. So now there are newer languages that incorporate these, even in the same level as `C` and `C++`.